# VB.NET - Issue with looping through rows in a datagrid

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, datagridview

```
 For Each row As DataRow In dgrFarms.Rows
        Dim sendtroopid As Integer
        sendtroopid = row("idColumn")
        'Do Something
Next
```

I've been trying to get a loop through a row in just one column in VB.NET for a while now, and i've done my homework on it too. When i use that code above I get:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' to type 'System.Data.DataRow'.

I saw another guide which told me to do:

```
For Each row As DataGridView In dgrFarms.Rows
        sendtroopid = row("idColumn")
        'Do Something
Next
```

But that gives me the error:

Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Item' accepts this number of arguments.

(That's a blue underline on 'Row("idColumn") )

Comment: Taking a step back for a second... Do you really want to loop through the rows of the UI element (the data grid), or do you actually want to loop through the rows of the _data_ to which the UI element is bound?  There are scenarios for the former, but the latter is far more common.

Comment: 'Aye, the data, what do I do differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code should be:

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgrFarms.Rows
    sendtroopid = row.Cells("idColumn").Value
    'Do Something
Next
```

Note that each row is a `DataGridViewRow`, not a `DataGridView`. Also, you get the contents of a specific cell from this row with the `Cells` property.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it would be something simple!

Answer (score 1):

This is a function I use in all my Apps:

```
''' <summary>
''' Provides the Properties and Methods to insert each Column from eaqch Row in a Dataset
''' when given a Dataset and a List Box 
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Class clsDisplayDataset
    Private mstrClsTitle As String = "clsDisplayDataset"

    ''' <summary>
    ''' For Each Row and Each Column create a single line to be inserted into the 
    ''' List Box
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="idsDataset"></param>
    ''' <param name="ilstListBox"></param>
    ''' <returns>True   -    When successful
    '''          False  -    When unsuccessful</returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Function DisplayDataSet(ByVal idsDataset As DataSet,
                                   ByRef ilstListBox As ListBox) As Boolean
        Dim lstrRowValue As String = ""
        Try
            For Each ldsRow As DataRow In idsDataset.Tables(0).Rows
                lstrRowValue = ""
                For Each ldsCol As DataColumn In idsDataset.Tables(0).Columns
                    lstrRowValue = lstrRowValue & ldsRow(ldsCol.ColumnName).ToString() & vbTab
                Next
                ilstListBox.Items.Add(lstrRowValue)
            Next
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            DisplayDataSet = False
            Throw New Exception(mstrClsTitle & ".DisplayDataSet" & vbCrLf &
                                "Error Number      [" & Err.Number & vbCrLf &
                                "Error Description [" & Err.Description & "]" & vbCrLf &
                                "Failed to insert columns into List Box")
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run your code by checking the itemType of the row being bound? try placing your code between:

```
If (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem) Then
'do loop
end if
```

Comment: Take in mind coment by David. Also, to add to this answer, The row can be a Header row (which has it's own type)

Comment: I'm not overly confident with VB yet, I have no idea what this does, or how to implement it into my own code. I just get a load of blue underlines when I try this.